# CSS code for multiplication-x doesn't work as a value of content property

Tags: css, styled-components

`styled-components` doesn't seem to be applying styles when `content: "\2715"` property is used. Does it have to do with parsing since commenting that property doesn't work either? It only works if I completely remove that line. However, it is not the case with `content: "\00a9"` which is for copyright symbol. It works for some codes but doesn't for others.

Check the demo here *(Removing content property applies other styles, commenting the line doesn't work)*: https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-forest-x6r8w

I've double checked the css code for it, that doesn't seem to be an issue: https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/multiplication-x/

Comment: Hmm, looks like the example is incorrect, should probably be `content: "\u2715"` instead as it's the unicode.

Comment: `\u2715` does work for symbol `x` but then why doesn't it fail for copyright symbol `\00a9`? Something weird seems to be going on.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to sanitation, I guess. It works if you add another backslash like `content: "\\2715"`

Comment: This also seems to work. Why does it selectively sanitize though? Shoudn't it fail for all the cases?

Comment: maybe it works for codes starting with zeros or double-zeros